# Adding formula to the pivot

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Can we add a specific formula, such as TODAY to the pivot table in excel? or in google sheets? or both? I know google sheets has a function called calculated fields but i could not enter the today function for sorting data in pivot.

Also in excel i can not do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A pivot table summarizes data. It is not clear what you want to achieve. Please edit your question and add a data sample and a sample result of the pivot table. Also, decide if you want to use Excel OR Google sheets. Not both. The answers will be different.

Comment: In excel, you cannot use functions that return variable results, such as RAND and NOW, database functions, or the GETPIVOTDATA function in Pivot Table formulas.